# How to refer to a WinForms label from a class

Tags: c#

I have Form1 and class in file called AbstractClass.cs.

I want to call a label in Form1 and assign msg string to the text in that lable.

How can I do that???

here is my class.

```
//"Concrete CPUMoon" drived from AbstractCPU class when Diagnosticing CPU for Moon system
class CPUMoon : AbstractCPU
{
    public override void DisplayName(AbstractCPU a)
    {
        //Form1 f1 = new Form1();

        string msg;
        // create reader & open file
        StreamReader tr = new StreamReader("Moon.txt");
        String fromFile = tr.ReadLine();
        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
        msg = "CPU diagnosing has be done for   " + a.GetType().Name + "                " + fromFile;
        //Console.WriteLine("CPU diagnosing has be done for   " + a.GetType().Name + "                //" + fromFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to explain your problem in detail!! Can't you just assign using the label name/id. lblName = msg;

Comment: Is the label already on the form? Is the DisplayName method running on the same thread as the form? If so, you can do this (with the label named "label1":

label1.Text = msg;

Comment: I want to pass a string in class to a label in another form!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All You need is a Property in your class and then call this property from the class like

```
   public class AnyCLass
   {
       public string Message{get; set;}
       // any other methods or properties in class ...
       // note thatin any method which you change the Message content it should be 
       // used and if you do not call the method which change the Message value ,
       // you have a string.Empty value
       // to test this change the Message Value in Constructor like below

       public AnyClass()
       {
          this.Message = "You have to change the value somewhere which call with user";
       }
   }

   public partial class Form1.cs
   {
       AnyClass instance = new AnyClass();
       Label1.Text = instance.Message;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

in your CPUMoon Class
  create a property called

```
class CPUMoon : AbstractCPU
{
    public string message {get;set;}
    public override void DisplayName(AbstractCPU a)
    {
        //Form1 f1 = new Form1();

        // create reader & open file
        StreamReader tr = new StreamReader("Moon.txt");
        String fromFile = tr.ReadLine();
        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
        message = "CPU diagnosing has be done for   " + a.GetType().Name + "                " + fromFile;
        //Console.WriteLine("CPU diagnosing has be done for   " + a.GetType().Name + "                //" + fromFile);
    }
}
```

in Your Form1 Class, Call the CPUMoon method and use the public message property in Form1 Label.

```
CPUMoon c = new CPUMoon();
label1.Text = c.Message;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply I did but when I call the method from the form it will return null message.

 CPUMoon c = new CPUMoon();
            lbl1.Text= c.message;

any advice??

Comment: put the debug point in DisplayName method and see what is coming?

Comment: `c.Message` is empty, because `DisplayName()` was not called.

Answer (score 1):

Controls on a form are private.  If you want to be able to modify the properties of one from some external class, then you need to make your form expose a public property to do so:

```
public class Form1
{
    public string MyMessage
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set { label1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Then it becomes trivial to reference:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.MyMessage = "...";
```

I do have to point out that what you're writing looks some pretty crazy spaghetti code.  But without knowing the details of what you're trying to do, this is about as much advice as anyone can offer.

Comment: @Eyla: What returns `null`?  The property getter?  It will return whatever the label's text is.  You'll have to be more specific about what you're doing and what the problem is in order for me to help debug it.